# Image alignment on html page with bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to fix these photos to be a tiny more centered. Maybe shift down a little and to the left. I am using all bootstrap and do not have any css attached to this. It is all working within the ul tags. Any help appreciated.

[Page Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpoJq.png)

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="dropdown-header">
            <strong>Example</strong><br />
            <span class="megasubheader">| NEWS AND CONTENT </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li class="list-group">
        <a href="https://example.com" class="list-group-item mt-2" aria-current="true">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <img id="imgsrc1" width="75px" height="75px" class="rounded mx-2">
                <span id="Htitle1" style="font-size: 14px"></span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="list-group-item mt-2" aria-current="true">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <img id="imgsrc2" width="75px" height="75px" class="rounded mx-2">
                <span id="Htitle2" style="font-size: 14px"></span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="list-group-item mt-2" aria-current="true">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <img id="imgsrc3" width="75px" height="75px" class="rounded mx-2">
                <span id="Htitle3" style="font-size: 14px"></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you share a working minimal working example of your code?

Comment: Your question qould be better if you edited your answer to use the snippet tool  `<>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `my-auto` on your img element.

[image]

Comment: I as well got my-auto in there. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Would this help your situation ?

```
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between flex-row align-items-center">
                <img id="imgsrc3" width="75px" height="75px" class="rounded me-2">
                <span id="Htitle3" style="font-size: 14px"></span>
            </div>
```

More over bootstrap spacing:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/

I saw that your text is long, so that has an effect too on it, with less text for me it works fine. hope this helps.